# returning the number of days between 2 dates is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, time

I have a small code that picks up the dates from a json file.
and returns the amount of days left before it expires.

How ever its returning **NaN** in console log.

```js
var start = "2019/03/12";
var end = "2020/03/12";
days = (end- start) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
console.log(Math.round(days));
```

this should be correct. but its not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a string to a date in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-a-string-to-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `end` and `start` to [**Date**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Syntax)

```js
var start = "2019/03/12";
var end = "2020/03/12";
days = ( new Date(end)- new Date(start) ) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
console.log(Math.round(days));
```

Comment: thank you so much.
i will mark as correct in 13 minutes.

Comment: Bear in mind that this won't work everywhere. The parsing of the **string** `"2020/03/12"` to the date you expect will depend on the location of the user. i.e. is this 12th march of the 3rd of December? A better solution to this is to use moment.js

Comment: To add to @Liam 's comment, you can combat that with [toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString).

Answer (score 0):

Try this...using [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) objects

```js
var start = new Date("2019/03/12");
var end = new Date("2020/03/12");
days = (end - start) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
console.log(Math.round(days));
```

Comment: Works, but lacks explanation. Living up to your username ;)

Comment: There, added an explanation

Answer (score 0):

you have to convert your string date into a javascript date but overall i would recommend to use moment as javascript dates can be a pain

to convert your string into a javascript datetype you can do it like this

```
var mydate = new Date('2011-04-11T10:20:30Z'); // <--- you have to format it
```

approach 2)

```
new Date('2011', '04' - 1, '11', '11', '51', '00')
```

if you want to use moment, you can do it like this:

```
var mydate = moment("2014-02-27T10:00:00").format('DD-MM-YYYY'); // <-- here inside the format function you can define how your string get's parsed
```

Comment: Moment is great, however for this particular example it's not required. The other answers are simple enough.

Comment: @Liam toLocaleString() will fix that without having to load an external library. Don't get me wrong, I love moment and would probably use it myself for something like this.

Comment: yeah thats true, moment is awesome, i usually use it for time calculations but of course you can always go down to the timestamp and calculate with it if you have a javascript date.
best functions for date calculating is dotnet with its timespan and datetime types, moment should improve into that direction and javascript should include moment in its syntax by default

Comment: `you have to format it` this works because it is a [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date string which **always** works

Comment: you are right in this case @Liam but i wanted to point out in general that  it needs a specific format to work

Answer (score -1):

Use `diff` function of `moment.js`. But you have to format it before use.

```js
const format = date => date.replace(/\//g, '-') 

var start = moment(format("2019/03/12"));
var end = moment(format("2020/03/12"));

console.log(end.diff(start, 'days'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I don't know why this one is down voted. you have my support.